# Connection Reset java after 10 minutes

Tags: java, connection, reset

i have a problem with java, this problem is really strange..im write a client server application, this server suppor login function, after login i can use the application, the problem is that, if i not use the app for 10 minutes when i try to do somethings on the app , i see Connection Reset error on the stack log, the problem appear ONLY if i not use the app for 10 minutes, after 10 minutes for re use the app i must do again the login.. i cant post the code is over 5000 lines.. how i can solve that problem?

Comment: Try to use a tcp-keep-alive http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP_keepalive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: socket read time out exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406628/java-socket-read-time-out-exception)

Comment: @EvanKnowles doesn't look like a duplicate to me. This appears to be about keeping a connection alive.

Comment: i not have timeout exception but connection reset exception after 10 minutes when i try to read on the socket , i send a byte on the client after i have sended a byte i wait for the client answer and when i try to read i have this exception..

Answer (score 1):

Try using this: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive%28boolean%29).

```
public void setKeepAlive(boolean on)
                  throws SocketException
Enable/disable SO_KEEPALIVE.
Parameters:
on - whether or not to have socket keep alive turned on.
```

Comment: someone fixed something similar with this: 
Windows Control Panel > Installed Updated > Turn Windows Features on or Off > (CheckBox) Simple TCPIP services (i.e. echo, daytime etc)